# Copy files from multiple sub-directories to the same destination directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory

We have almost 300 subdirectories in main directory. Now we want to copy all files from subdirectories in a single command to Destination directory. Is it possible?

```
Main Directory
     SubDirectory
        SubsubDirectory1
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
        SubsubDirectory2
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
     SubDirectory
        SubsubDirectory1
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
        SubsubDirectory2
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
     SubDirectory
        SubsubDirectory1
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
        SubsubDirectory2
           xx.jpg
           xx,jpg
```

I found below command can do work. But it is hard to mention each and every subdirectory name in the command.

```
cp "Main Directory"/*/Subsubdirectory1/* destdir
```

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command is a good tool for that kind of operation, best in combination with `xargs`.
Try something like:

```
find "Main Directory" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t destdir
```

and have a look at `man find`, `man xargs` and `man cp` for details on how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) in *recursive* mode (`**`) :

```
shopt -s globstar

cp -l **/*.jpg 'Main Directory'/
```

I use `-l` switch to avoid wasting disk space, it create hard links

Comment: Yes, post edited accordingly